# What temperature to froth/steam OAT milk to? {Rancilio Silvia}

Tags: temperature

I have a v3 Rancilio Silvia with PID and just cant find anything solid online. Thanks. Currently set to 280 (Fahrenheit) but thats way tooooo high.

Looking to make lattes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the PID setting at 280 F is set to control the boiler temperature. For steaming there may be another setting, but it's probably unnecessary - as long as steam leaves the wand you can steam your oat milk.

I place my hand on the side of my metal jug to judge when I think my oat milk is steamed to perfection (I think I like it slightly cooler than most). I made myself an oat milk flat white just now and measured the final temperature at 58 C (136 F). I believe some may prefer it at up to 158 F, just like with cow's milk (there may even be some who prefer it slightly cooler).

Regarding the 280 F setting, I'd recommend setting it to 205 F, tasting an espresso shot and if it's bitter go a little lower toward 195 F. If you taste sourness you need the boiler temperature hotter or, perhaps, to grind the coffee finer.

Comment: Thank you - i have 221F for my grouphead - and the espresso comes out great. back to the steam - i also use my hand to gauge milk temp and i guess 280F produces plenty of great steam - and ill check later today to see what the steam temp comes out to be - ill aim for what you have - ~136F to about ~160F. thanks man.

Comment: @user3669548 that was the final milk temp :) steam will be roughly 100 C